# designing network enabled audio/video player with c#

Tags: c#

i have no idea how to make a streaming audio-video player through c#.
if anyone could help me how to get through this...

Comment: I would learn System.IO namespace like the back of my hand. Also, I would checkout the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you might want to consider:

1. The content of the media that you are sending (will it be variable bit rate, or constant)
2. How will you handle packet loss
3. What about network nonavailability
4. How will you handle positioning requests (requests to fast forward, jump etc)
5. What platforms/software will render the content (codecs, players, bandwidth)

Also you need to consider:

1. Prewritten media streaming servers
2. Codecs and library (take a look at DirectShow)
3. UI for the user to respond to the content shown
4. Media streaming formats
5. Packages that can estimate available bandwidth well
6. Bandwidth based encoding [reduces the quality for low bandwidth applications]

Comment: thanx steven, it will be helpful if u could tell me where to find n look for these stuffs